# spring cloud dataflow enable security on cloudfoundry

Tags: security, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to setup security for SCDF on PCF

based on documentation is it possible to enabled security for SCDF dashboard

when running examples provided on locally installed server 
even the easiest example

```
java -jar spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local/target/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local-1.2.1.RELEASE.jar \
--security.basic.enabled=true \
--security.user.name=test \
--security.user.password=pass \
--security.user.role=VIEW
```

it runs correctly - dashboard shows login screen

however
for PCF deployment 
it is not documented how to achieve this

I tried on setting environment variables for server app on various ways but no positive results (e.g. SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON etc)

It would be great to understand how to do that. 
Best if authorisation use PCF user/password and without need to build the customised server jar.

SCDF tile on PCF would be great help I guess

looking forward to hearing from you
best regards
Wojtek

Answer (score 0):

For Cloud Foundry, it'd be recommended to either use the [SSO/UAA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-cloudfoundry/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-security-cloud-foundry) integration for a more seamless security solution.

If you're interested in a development/exploration level security solution, you could use the Basic Auth support. It is unclear how the auth credentials are passed to the server, though. The env-var `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON` is indeed the preferred approach to pass auth credentials to the server.

Comment: Thank you for your hints;
UAA integration works fine now for me